# Json encoding unicode characters as hexidecimal after converting from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

After converting my application from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core, one of my endpoints which returns json has changed from encoding unicode characters in decimal to now encoding them as hexadecimal.

The returned data:

```
£1,500.00
```

Before:

```
&#163;1,500.00
```

After:

```
&#xA3;1,500.00
```

I'm guessing that I need to set the `JsonSerializerOptions` in `Program.cs`, but I'm not sure what the setting is.

Comment: _"one of my endpoints which returns json"_ - do you mean XML instead of JSON?

Comment: No, it's a bit of a weird setup, but it returns a json object - one of the properties of that object is a htmlTemplate, which is mostly html with some custom symbols

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in current implementation https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0c25851268670b30661e87f8ad1bdfb2310f6cd5/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/DefaultHtmlEncoder.cs#L91

Seems like you need to implement your own `HtmlEncoder`.

Comment: I don't think this quite solves the problem.  It just means the £ is not encoded.  What I'm after is making unicode characters become encoded as decimal values instead of hexidecimal values

Comment: @Andy bad news for you